# Copy an Excel sheet to new sheet including formatting - C#

Tags: c#, excel, copy-paste, worksheet

I need to create one method that it's able to copy an excel sheet and then, paste it on a new excel sheet in the same workbook, but it's necessary to copy the formatting as well.

I found several codes, but all of them not copy the formatting, only the text.
below the code that I wrote:

```
        // Opening Excel File
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = null;
        excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(file, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets sheets = workbook.Worksheets;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(1);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sheet2 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(2);


        // Copy the source sheet
        Object defaultArg = Type.Missing;

        sheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];
        sheet.UsedRange.Copy(defaultArg);

        // Paste on destination sheet
        sheet2.UsedRange._PasteSpecial(XlPasteType.xlPasteValues, XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, false, false);

        workbook.Save();
        common.closeExcel(excel, workbook);
```

If anybody has any suggestion, please let me know.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you try/read about the various values of `XlPasteType`and `XlPasteSpecialOperation` ?

Comment: Thanks DrKoch, I changed XlPasteType.xlPasteValues to XlPasteType.xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme and worked better.

Answer (score -4):

This will make an exact copy of a sheet to a new sheet renamed as the original :

```
Dim x = 2
For numtimes = 1 To x 
Sheet1.Copy _
After:=Sheet1
Next
```

Comment: The is VBA not C#